# what is the difference between host and slot in mulicore-multiprocessor environment?

Tags: c++, c, multiprocessing, mpi, openmpi

i know that resource manager(R.M.) conveys slot information to openmpi but

1. how R.M. determines number of slots in a multi-core processor(is 1 core == 1 slot always?) and,
2. if i run a.out on a 4 core processor, then what is the difference between:

   - myshell$ mpirun --host n1,n1,n1,n1,n1 ./a.out
   - myshell$ mpirun -np 5 --host n1 ./a.out

I mean in which case ,am I "oversubscribing" the node ?

Comment: This is answered in the MPI FAQ's (https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=running#oversubscribing)

Comment: the FAQ is not clearly distinguishing processors(multi-uni) on basis on # of cores
so to be precise ..
is it wrong to say that "no. of cores"==no. of slots ?

Comment: I think it's safe to say #processors = #cores in MPI context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it comes to resource managers, e.g. SLURM, LSF, SGE/OGE, Torque, etc., the mapping between slots and cores is entirely left to the system administrator. It depends usually on the nature of the jobs that are to be executed on the nodes. In HPC, where most tasks are CPU-bound, the usual mapping is one slot per core (or per hardware thread). In data processing, where most tasks are I/O bound, having more slots than cores could be more beneficial.

The same applies to launching MPI processes. When the hosts are described in the hostfile, the number of slots per host does not necessarily have to match the hardware configuration. Again, it depends on the nature of the MPI job. Slot information is usually used to control how ranks are to be distributed. For example, the default policy in Open MPI is to fill the provided slots on the first host and then move to the next one. Once all hosts are filled, if more ranks remain to be launched, the process starts again from the first node in the host list.

The end effect of `--host n1,n1,n1,n1,n1` and `--host n1 -np 5` is the same: 5 ranks are launched on host `n1`. The difference is how Open MPI interprets it.

- `mpiexec --host n1,n1,n1,n1,n1 ./a.out` tells Open MPI that there are 5 slots on host `n1`. Since the `-np` parameter is omitted, `mpiexec` starts one rank per defined slot, therefore 5 ranks are started at host `n1`.
- `mpiexec --host n1 -np 5 ./a.out` tells Open MPI that there is a single slot on host `n1`. One rank is launched on `n1`. Since no more slots are left, `mpiexec` starts again from the first defined slot, i.e. launches another rank on host `n1`. This is repeated until all 5 ranks are launched on `n1` and results in it being oversubscribed.

Note that the node is oversubscribed only from the point of view of the MPI library - one slot was provided on `n1`, but it had to start 5 ranks there. This has nothing to do with oversubscribing the node itself, i.e. there could be much more CPU free cores than 5.

When the host list is provided by the resource manager, oversubscribing the nodes is a very bad idea, especially since some or all nodes might be shared with other jobs. In that case it is recommended that the `--nooversubscribe` option is used in order to prevent `mpiexec` from launching more ranks than slots granted. Note though that there are legitimate cases of oversubscription, e.g. when the nodes are granted exclusively (no sharing with other jobs) and the MPI job is I/O intensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify number of available slots on each host:

```
mpirun -np 5 --host n1:2,n2:3 ./a.out
```

This will run 2 processes on n1 and 3 on n2.